# Creating a new object when assigning from dropdown

Tags: django

In the Django admin, you can click the green "+" icon next to a dropdown field and create a new object instead of choosing one from the dropdown menu. I'd like to implement this on my site, but I'm not sure of the process going on here. How does the admin site return the new object to the dropdown menu after it's created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using bootstrap read about modals [Modals more info](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

Inside modal there'll be django form with POST method. If you want to do it asynchonously use AJAX and Django Rest Framework.

Comment: I'm sorry, now realized that's not the solution you wanted. To open new window, you have to use javascript.
`window.open("url", "window name")`

Comment: I loosely followed this process and was able to get it work with Bootstrap modals and AJAX. Thanks!